# Sediment screen in water heater outflow?

Tags: water-heater

At T-joint out of NEW water heater, line to bathroom is HOT while line to kitchen sink is COLD (NO hot flow).
Install was botched by inexperienced plumber, leaving leaks on pvc connections with both inflow AND outflow.
Old unit had SLOW hot flow on kitchen tap from possible mineral buildup.
Could there be a sediment SCREEN involved? If so, can the threaded T-joint be safely uncoupled for inspection, cleaning, and reuse?

Pic shows T-fitting with outflow to kitchen tap (with pressure release valve)...
Thanks for any ideas[image]

Comment: Is your kitchen sink supply connected to the output of the overpressure valve? Unclear why you have an overpressure valve there at all - the overpressure/overtemperature valve is generally required to be directly on the water heater and comes preinstalled on new ones. No water flow would be perfectly normal in that case.

Comment: I would seriously considering hiring a plumber to inspect your system and see what recommendations the plumber makes. I have a bad feeling this is only a precursor to the problems you have. At that point you will know what needs to be done. Food for thought,  did you hire an inspector before you purchased the home? If so did they state everything was OK?

Answer (score 2):

Most pressure release valves stop out flow till too much pressure builds up.  The outflow is the path to release high pressure.

To check have someone at the kitchen and release the pressure by hand with handle on the pressure release valve.

Pressure release valves should be on the hot water tank, not in the plumbing pipes.

To fix will need to turn off the hot water, release the pressure, and remove that pressure release valve.

Replace with either an elbow or a shut off valve if you do not have one by the sink.